# How to make a one page website with parallax scrolling working both desktop and mobile devices (also iOS)?

Tags: ios, mobile, scroll, desktop, parallax

How to make a one page website with **parallax** scrolling working both *desktop* and *mobile* devices (also **iOS**)?

This is my code for now... it speeds up 1 div when a scroll is triggered, but on iphone, it only moves when you let your finger off the screen and i'd like it to scroll smoother with a nice slide :)

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('#speedup').css('margin-top', (top/10)*-5);      

  });
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: @rckoenes This is my code for now... it speeds up 1 div when a scroll is triggered, but on iphone, it only moves when you let your finger off the screen and i'd like it to scroll smoother with a nice slide :) $(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
     var top = $(this).scrollTop();
     
     $('#speedup').css('margin-top', (top/10)*-5);      

   });
 });

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to use css2 media query, or using em instead of px for you css styles to ensure your browser supports both mobile/desktop web versions.

then, of course you need javascript to help you do the parallax scrolling for you web game/application